# Attempting to add a role queries 'AspNetRoles' instead of 'AspNetUserRoles'

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am working on a project and I am using the code first approach and I am using ASP .NET Core 3.0 and Entity Framework Core & Identity 3.0.0. I have defined my entitites and I would like to create two `IdentityRoles`, one as `Customer` and one as `Administrator`. For this, I have prepared the following method:

```
  public static IServiceProvider ConfigureDefaultRoles(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //TODO: figure out why the table is incorrectly named
        var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole<Guid>>>();
        var defaultUserRoles = new List<IdentityRole<Guid>>
        {
            new IdentityRole<Guid>() {Name = UserRoleDefinitions.CustomerRoleName},
            new IdentityRole<Guid>() {Name = UserRoleDefinitions.AdministratorRoleName}
        };

        foreach (var role in defaultUserRoles)
        {
            if (roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.Name).Result)
            {
                continue;
            }

            roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
        }

        return serviceProvider;
    }
```

This method is called by `Startup` as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
        app.ConfigureApplication();
        serviceProvider.ConfigureDefaultRoles();
    }
```

At startup, this results in teh following [error](https://pastebin.com/6EXMWgg4). The main problem here is that the role manager is trying to query the table `AspNetRoles` instead of `AspNetUserRoles`. I have made sure that the migrations have been applied. My db context is as follows:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>, IDbContext
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="options">The options for the application context builder</param>
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply the entity configurations defined in 'Configurations'.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="modelBuilder"></param>
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Call the base
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            // Apply the configurations defined in 'Configurations'
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly);
        }
    }
```

There are no roles implemented in this project, I am using `IdentityRole<Guid>`. Identity is configured as follows:

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureIdentity(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole<Guid>>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    return services;
}
```

My `User` is as follows: `User : IdentityUser<Guid>`. Furthermore, I have taken a look in `ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot` and I have noticed that indeed the table `AspNetRoles` is declared as using the named the error is complaining that is missing, but the table is re-constructed under the name `AspNetUserRoles`. Exploring the database file (`app.db` for development) shows only `AspNetUserRoles`. Full snapshot available [here](https://pastebin.com/RTwK8hMr).

```
    modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole<System.Guid>", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("ConcurrencyStamp")
                        .IsConcurrencyToken()
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT")
                        .HasMaxLength(256);

                    b.Property<string>("NormalizedName")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT")
                        .HasMaxLength(256);

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("NormalizedName")
                        .IsUnique()
                        .HasName("RoleNameIndex");

                    b.ToTable("AspNetRoles");
                });


modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole<System.Guid>", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("UserId")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.Property<Guid>("RoleId")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.HasKey("UserId", "RoleId");

                    b.HasIndex("RoleId");

                    b.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
                });
```

Obviously, I am missing a point..

Thanks!

Comment: `AspNetRoles` and `AspNetUserRoles` are different tables and both must exist. Check if the migrations are applied to the database pointed by the  connection string.

Comment: I have already applied the migrations. I have also dropped the database and applied the migrations again, then update-database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @IVan said, both tables indeed existed. The issues was that I had a context builder which was pointing to a data-source located in the 'Persistence' project. However, the WebUI was trying to access the same data-source from its project directory. This resulted in a new data-source without any tables or migrations.

I have managed to fix this by switching to SQLServer (local db) for development.